# Why do I get two lines for every index entry when creating a libreoffice writer alphabetic index?

Tags: libreoffice

The base of the entry is on the first line and the page(s) are on line 2.

After some trial and error I have decided that when it creates the index it inserts a "tab, CR, Tab" between the base of the entry and the Page(s) numbers.

I have followed all the instructions but the result is the same every time.

Why is this the case?